# Find the path for Pacman from expanded/explored nodes

Tags: python, pacman, breadth-first-search

I implemented a BFS for Pacman. I am getting correct list for nodes expanded. But, I couldn't find the path between Pacman and food. For simplicity, I reversed the stack into queue in the following code.

```
''' A Sample BFS Algorithm '''

import pprint
def bfs( r, c, pacman_r, pacman_c, food_r, food_c, grid):

    stack = [(pacman_r-1,pacman_c),(pacman_r,pacman_c-1),(pacman_r,pacman_c+1),(pacman_r+1,pacman_c)]
    queue = stack[::-1]


    visited = []
    path = []

    print 'The pacman start',grid[pacman_r][pacman_c]
    count = 0
    while grid[pacman_r][pacman_c] != '.':

        move = queue.pop()

        if move not in visited:
            visited.append(move)
            new_r, new_c  = move[0], move[1]

            if grid[new_r][new_c] == '-':
                path.append((new_r,new_c))
                print 'The path', (new_r, new_c)

                pacman_r = new_r
                pacman_c = new_c
                new_stack = [(pacman_r-1,pacman_c),(pacman_r,pacman_c-1),(pacman_r,pacman_c+1),(pacman_r+1,pacman_c)]
                new_queue = new_stack[::-1]
                queue = new_queue + queue
                count = count+1


            if grid[new_r][new_c] == '.':
                print "The destination", (new_r, new_c)
                pacman_r = new_r
                pacman_c = new_c
                count = count + 1

    print "Count", count

    return

pacman_r = 3
pacman_c = 9

food_r = 5
food_c = 1

r = 7
c = 20



grid = ['%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%', '%--------------%---%', '%-%%-%%-%%-%%-%%-%-%', '%--------P-------%-%', '%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%-%', '%.-----------------%', '%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%']

bfs(r, c, pacman_r, pacman_c, food_r, food_c, grid)
```

My `pacman_bfs` is able to expand all nodes correctly. The output I am obtaining is

```
3 9
3 8
3 10
3 7
2 10
3 11
2 7
3 6
1 10
3 12
1 7
3 5
1 9
1 11
3 13
1 6
1 8
3 4
1 12
2 13
3 14
1 5
2 4
3 3
1 13
3 15
1 4
3 2
1 14
3 16
1 3
3 1
2 16
1 2
2 1
1 16
1 1
1 17
1 18
2 18
3 18
4 18
5 18
5 17
5 16
5 15
5 14
5 13
5 12
5 11
5 10
5 9
5 8
5 7
5 6
5 5
5 4
5 3
5 2
5 1
```

But this the list of expanded nodes. The path between the Pacman denoted by `"P"` and food `'.'` is

```
3 9
3 10
3 11
3 12
3 13
3 14
3 15
3 16
2 16
1 16
1 17
1 18
2 18
3 18
4 18
5 18
5 17
5 16
5 15
5 14
5 13
5 12
5 11
5 10
5 9
5 8
5 7
5 6
5 5
5 4
5 3
5 2
5 1
```

The total path is `32`. I don't know where I am having problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from Queue import Queue
def bfs(numRows, numCols, pacmanPos, grid):
    q = Queue()
    q.put((pacmanPos, [pacmanPos]))
    visited = set([pacmanPos])
    while not q.empty():
        currentPos, path = q.get()
        row, column = currentPos
        if grid[row][column] == '.':
            return len(path), path
        for newPos in [(row, column + 1), (row + 1, column), (row, column - 1), (row - 1, column)]:
            if newPos not in visited and newPos[0] < numRows and newPos[1] < numCols and grid[newPos[0]][newPos[1]] != '%':
                q.put((newPos, path + [newPos]))
                visited.add(newPos)

    return 0, []

r = 7
c = 20

pacmanPos = (3, 9)

grid = ['%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%', 
        '%--------------%---%', 
        '%-%%-%%-%%-%%-%%-%-%', 
        '%--------P-------%-%', 
        '%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%-%', 
        '%.-----------------%', 
        '%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%']

pathLength, path = bfs(r, c, pacmanPos, grid)
print 'Path Length: {} \nPath: {}'.format(pathLength, path)
```

Multiple paths are possible depending on which orientation sequence you go with. I'm exploring right, down, left, up. The path might change based on that.

**Output**

```
Path Length: 33 
Path: [(3, 9), (3, 10), (3, 11), (3, 12), (3, 13), (3, 14), (3, 15), (3, 16), (2, 16), (1, 16), (1, 17), (1, 18), (2, 18), (3, 18), (4, 18), (5, 18), (5, 17), (5, 16), (5, 15), (5, 14), (5, 13), (5, 12), (5, 11), (5, 10), (5, 9), (5, 8), (5, 7), (5, 6), (5, 5), (5, 4), (5, 3), (5, 2), (5, 1)]
```

Comment: I understood. But where my program and your program differ in approach? i reversing stack and use it as queue.